# Can I use existing AWS IAM role to create S3 bucket via Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to create a S3 Bucket via CloudFormation template. I found there is a way to do it for EC2 instance on [this link](https://hackernoon.com/attach-an-iam-role-to-an-ec2-instance-with-cloudformation-33c517a8d4c3).

Do we have a way to create S3 bucket using existing IAM role via cloudformation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an S3 bucket via CloudFormation Template.
Make sure your role has the proper permissions to perform this action.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html for examples